# Having problems with sqlite3, getting syntax error?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

When using sqlite3's database, I get an error like so:

```
    File '..\database.py', line 131, in load_player_abilities
      (player.id, ability.id)):

sqlite3.OperationalError: near '=': syntax error
```

The error I'm getting is coming from the following piece of code:

```
for ability in player.abilities:
    for level in cursor.execute(
            "SELECT level FROM abilities"
            "WHERE player_id=? AND ability_id=?",
            (player.id, ability.id)):
        ability.level = level
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing a space between `abilities` and `WHERE`.

```
for ability in player.abilities:
    for level in cursor.execute(
        "SELECT level FROM abilities "
        "WHERE player_id=? AND ability_id=?",
        (player.id, ability.id)):
        ability.level = level
```